# Setting up a single node Hadoop cluster on Mac

Tags: java, macos, hadoop

After setting Java path and Hadoop distribution file, when I'm trying to check  the usage document I'm getting errors. I'm confused even if have set the path right. This is how I have set the path.

The following is displayed in terminal

`/Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 26: JAVA_HOME=${/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
}: bad substitution`

`/Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh: line 35: HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${"/Users/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0
"}: bad substitution`

Comment: I think you just need `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home`... By doing `${...}` you are trying to do a variable substitution

Comment: thank you solved the java -path problem with java, but when trying bin/hadoop ,Usage: hadoop [--config confdir] COMMAND.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing `${...}` you are trying to do a variable substitution, thus your error.

Change to `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home` instead.

---

Alternatively, I think this is better

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

And you can see it works like so

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME                                               
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home
```

---

Also, [following the tutorial](http://sungsoo.github.io/2015/09/01/hadoop-installation-on-mac-os-x-yosemite.html), it doesn't literally mean put the `{/path/to/folder}`

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX={your hadoop distribution directory}
```

It wants you to do this for wherever you downloaded the package to

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/Users/hadoop/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0
```

---

Then adding to the `PATH` would look something like

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
export PATH=$HADOOP_PREFIX:$PATH
```

Comment: I did change that path, actually i'm following this article to set up 'http://sungsoo.github.io/2015/09/01/hadoop-installation-on-mac-os-x-yosemite.html'

Comment: But i'm not able to set path  export HADOOP_PREFIX={your hadoop distribution directory}

Comment: When i tried export PATH =$PATH{ /Users/hadoop/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0} following error comes:line 36: export: `=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin{/Users/hadoop/Downloads/hadoop-2.6.0}': not a valid identifier

Comment: I have made the changes to my answer. If you just want a pre-built single node hadoop cluster to learn on, though, I would suggest using either the Cloudera QuickStart VM or HortonWorks sandbox. Then you don't need to mess with any installation, just run a VM.